# VBA Split String Loop

Tags: string, vba, excel, split

I am trying to split a string and create a loop for going through the cells in the column.There are a few challenges:

1. Split works for `ActiveCell` only.
2. Loop goes through all cells until LastRow but populates all cells
   with split string values from `ActiveCell` only.
3. Split of Array starts with `i = 0` even though there is `Option Base 1`
   at the beginning of the Module.
4. How can I change the location of destination (e.g. instead of
   splitting string next to existing data, is there an option to manage
   column numbers)?

Thank you

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub SplitStringLoop()

    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim y As Integer
    Dim FullName As Variant
    Dim LastRow As Single

    ReDim FullName(3)

    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    txt = ActiveCell.Value

    FullName = Split(txt, "-")

    For y = 2 To LastRow

            For i = 1 To UBound(FullName)

                Cells(y, i + 1).Value = FullName(i)

            Next i

   Next y

End Sub
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Chris Nelisen outlined the reasons, I had this code written before he posted, so I'll post it anyway.

```
Option Explicit

Sub SplitStringLoop()

Dim txt As String
Dim i As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim FullName As Variant
Dim LastRow As Single

ReDim FullName(3)

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For y = 2 To LastRow
        Cells(y, 1).Select
        txt = ActiveCell.Value
        FullName = Split(txt, "-")
        For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)
           Cells(y, i + 2).Value = FullName(i)
        Next i
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Chris, thank you for the adjusted code and detailed explanations!!! The case is closed.Have a great day!!!

Answer (score 0):

To address the issues you list

1. `Split` acts on the string you pass to it.  *You* are passing the active cell value to it.
2. You don't update the result of split (`FullName`) inside the loop.  So what else do you expect?
3. `Split` *Returns a zero-based, one-dimensional array*.  It says so right there in the help.  `Option Base 1` specifies the *default* lower bound, for when you don't specify it in a `Dim` statement.
4. You are specifying the column in your code `Cells(y, i + 1)` (`i + 1` in this case).  If you want it somewhere else, specify a different column.

Comment: Thank you, Chris, for your explicit comments. I am new to VBA and I really appreciate not just a code but a detailed explanation.Anyway I am still struggling with making proper changes. 1. When I replace ActiveCell with Range ( txt = Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1)).Value) it gives me a type mismatch error. Probably it is because   Dim txt As String. If I change Dim txt As Range, I have an error "Object variable or With block variable not set. I think String is a correct datatype as I have to split text rather than range.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

this is my sulotion

```
Public Function CheckEmailsValid(EmailAddresses As String) As Boolean
On Error GoTo Err_1
    Dim V_Tempi As Integer
    Dim V_Email As Variant
    
    For Each V_Email In Split(EmailAddresses, ";")
        V_Tempi = V_Tempi + 1
        If CheckEmailValid(V_Email) = False Then
            MyMsgBox 2, "Email " & V_Tempi & " Is invalid"
            CheckEmailValidFew = False
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next
    CheckEmailValidFew = True

Exit_1:
    Exit Function
Err_1:
    MyMsgBox 2, "Error !!" & vbCr & Err.Number & vbCr & Err.Description
End Function
```