# Return multiple lines

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a large body of text and am trying to extract parts of that into a field in my form. I am using the following code:

```
If InStr(1, abody(j), "Extent of Work:", 1) Then
    strExtWork = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Extent of Work:") + 16)
End If
```

This works well in returning one line, but sometimes the extent of work that I am trying to extract is multiple lines and I have kind of hit a wall... any ideas?

Here is a sample of the text:

```
SEQUENCE NUMBER     CDC = RIC 

Transmit:  Date: 

*** R O U T I N E         *** Request No.: 000000000

Operators Notified: 


Start Date/Time:    01/01/18   At 00:15  Expiration Date: 01/01/18 

Location Information: 
County:     Municipality: 
Subdivision/Community:  
Street:               0 FAKE ST
Nearest Intersection: FAKE ST
Other Intersection:    
Lat/Lon: 
Type of Work: REPAIR  
Block:                Lot:                Depth: 2FT 

Extent of Work:  BEGINS 53FT W OF C/L OF INTERSECTION AND EXTENDS 785FT
  W.  MARK A 3FT RADIUS OF POLE NUMBERS 000/000, 000/000

Remarks:  
  Working For Contact:  NO ONE

Working For: NO ONE
Address:     123 FAKE ST
City:        SPRINGFIELD
Phone:       555-555-5555   Ext:  

Excavator Information: 
Caller:      NO ONE
Phone:       555-555-5555   Ext:  

Excavator:   NO ONE

Address:     123 FAKE ST
City:        SPRINGFIELD
Phone:       555-555-5555   Ext:          Fax:  
Cellular:     
Email:       EMAIL@EMAIL.COM

End Request
```

I just now noticed that if the extent of work field only has one line it will not import. It only imports if there are multiple lines, any ideas? Here is the code I am using:

```
Dim rowOffset As Long

If InStr(1, abody(j), "Extent of Work:", 1) Then
    strExtWork = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Extent of Work:") + 16)
    rowOffset = 1 ' reinit
    While Left(abody(j + rowOffset), 8) <> "Remarks:" ' check if this is Remarks:
        strExtWork = strExtWork & abody(j + rowOffset)
        rowOffset = rowOffset + 1
        Me.ExtentofWork = Trim(strExtWork)
    Wend
End If
```

Comment: Please put data sample for your question

Comment: data sample? what would you like me to provide?

Comment: I mean some part of text you try to parse.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you need to find a common splitter value of the text to use with the Split command, use that to parse the text into an array, then loop the array to build your text.

Here is an example:

[VBA Split String Loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989043/vba-split-string-loop)

Comment: thanks for the response! what i was trying( and failing so far) is to have all of the text returned after "extent of work" until it finds a certain word (remarks), because this is a constant in the text. I am importing data that is not in a great format and trying to manipulate it for my needs. This is the first time I have tried something like this. I have looked at your sample link but am struggling with the application. any further help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post text with your original question?

Answer (score 0):

If there are always empty line after `Extent of Work:`:

```vb
Dim rowOffset as long

If InStr(1, abody(j), "Extent of Work:", 1) Then
    strExtWork = Mid(abody(j), InStr(abody(j), "Extent of Work:") + 16)

    rowOffset = 1 ' reinit 
    While trim(abody(j + rowOffset)) <> ""  ' check if this is empty separator line
        strExtWork = strExtWork & abody(j + rowOffset)
        rowOffset = rowOffset + 1
    Wend
```

If there is allways `Remarks:` after `Extent of Work`, change loop condition to:

```vba
While left(abody(j + rowOffset),8) <> "Remarks:"  ' check if this is Remarks:
```

Comment: Sorry i messed up the formatting of the sample text, there is never an empty line after extent of work, so i used your code  to check remarks and it is still only returning the first line and the app actually freezes afterwards now.

Comment: actually had a mistake in entering the code- i have corrected it and it runs fine but it still only shows the first line in extent of work

Comment: got it! had to add Me.ExtentofWork = Trim(strExtWork) after the loop and now it seems to work

Comment: any idea why it will not include any text if is only a single row?

Comment: @didacticone `Me.ExtentofWork = Trim(strExtWork)` must be after `Wend`