# Loop multiple split functions

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm new to VBA, so thank you in advance for your patience. I wrote a sub that  takes the part number (PN) in Range C2 and performs three different `split` and `left` functions to fill in the columns to the left and right of the PN with extracted portions of the PN string. Here is a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WiUIX.png) of the columns and what it fills in.

Here is my code so far:

```
Sub PN_Autotfill1()
Dim PN As Range
Dim SCPort_Type As Range
Dim SCPort_Size As Range
Dim Start_FittingSize As Range
Dim PN_String As String
Dim PN_1 As Variant
Dim PN_2 As Variant
Dim PN_3 As Variant

Set PN = Range("C2")
Set SCPort_Type = PN.Offset(, -2)
Set SCPort_Size = PN.Offset(, -1)
Set Start_FittingSize = PN.Offset(, 1)
PN_String = PN.Value
If InStr(PN_String, "Flange") > 0 Then
    'Splits PN into SC Port Type
    PN_1 = Split(PN_String, "#")(1)
    PN_2 = Left(PN_1, 2)
    SCPort_Type.Value = "#" & PN_2 & "Flange"
    
    'Splits PN into SC Port Size, Start, and End Fitting
    PN_3 = Split(PN_1, "-")(1)
    SCPort_Size = PN_3
    Start_FittingSize = PN_3
End If
End Sub
```

Now I want to make a loop that applies these functions to each cell containing a PN in column C. I've found some good examples on [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24989043/vba-split-string-loop) and a [VBA tutorial website](https://www.homeandlearn.org/the_split_function.html) that create loops for a single split function, but not for multiple split functions. It looks like two For loops will come into play: `LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row` with `For a = 2 To LastRow`, and `For i = 1 To UBound(Unsure what goes here)`. Does anyone have tips or example code for how to go about this? Thank you in advance for any help!

Here is the code with Jamheadart's answer integrated in:

```
Sub PN_Autotfill_Functions(PN As Range)
Dim SCPort_Type_Size As Range
Dim Start_FittingSize As Range
Dim PN_String As String
Dim LastRow As Single
Dim PN_1 As Variant
Dim PN_2 As Variant
Dim PN_3 As Variant

Set SCPort_Type_Size = PN.Offset(, -1)
Set Start_FittingSize = PN.Offset(, 1)
PN_String = PN.Value

LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

    If InStr(PN_String, "Flange") > 0 Then
        'Splits PN into SC Port Type and Size, then combines results
        PN_1 = Split(PN_String, "#")(1)
        PN_2 = Left(PN_1, 2)
        PN_3 = Split(PN_1, "-")(1)
        SCPort_Type_Size.Value = "#" & PN_2 & " Flange" & ", -" & PN_3
    
        'Fills in Start and End Fitting Size based on previous Split of PN
        Start_FittingSize = PN_3
    End If
End Sub

Sub PN_Autofill_Loop()
Dim a As Long
Dim PN As Range

Set PN = ActiveCell
    For a = 2 To 11
        PN_Autotfill_Functions Range("C" & a)
    Next a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need multiple loops, you just need to run your `sub` in a loop - and each time you run it, it will take in a range (e.g. `C2`)

So change your routine first line to this:

```
Sub PN_Autotfill1(PN as Range)
```

And **get rid** of these two lines:

```
Dim PN As Range
Set PN = Range("C2")
```

This means `PN` is now a parameter for the routine, instead of it being defined in the routine itself.

You could then call it for a few ranges, like this:

```
Sub Testing()
PN_Autotfill1 Range("C2")
PN_Autotfill1 Range("C4")
PN_Autotfill1 Range("C7")
End Sub
```

And finally if you want to loop through say ten rows you could call it in a loop with a different sub routine:

```
Sub LoopingExample
Dim i As Long
For i = 2 to 11
    PN_Autotfill1 Range("C" & i)
Next i
End Sub
```

---

It's worth noting that this ease is only possible because your original code is constructed quite well (e.g. it's using `Offset` instead of hard-coded ranges etc.)

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you @jamheadart . I'll give this a try and see how it goes.

Comment: That works!!! I implemented the loop, and the only thing I added was ```Dim PN As Range``` and ```Set PN = ActiveCell``` in the loop sub. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to help, have fun with VBA - I got hooked a few years ago and I'm still loving it :D